# What happens when Most Wanted cars get away?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I raced the Alpha Romeo 4C Concept in a Most Wanted race, but after the race I was busted by the cops and it got away.

Now when I look at Most Wanted Race 10 in the Easy Drive list I see the following;

[image]

Does this mean that the car is driving around somewhere in the game world? If so, where can I find it?

Would it just be easier to re-run the race and hope for better luck with the cops next time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most Wanted cars you've already beaten in a race will re-spawn behind you while you're driving around in the world (and *not* in a race). Usually it only takes about 5 minutes for them to re-appear. If you lose them again, just keeping driving around until they come back. They will keep coming back until you shut them down.

Comment: Ah - this explains why one of the most wanted cars I needed to shut down spawned on a remote road I was driving around just after taking this screenshot!